# Pontuação diminui de um dia para outro no site principal

Tags: debate, pontos

Venho notando que de um dia para outro a pontuação diminui 2 pontos.

Eu tinha notado isso no final de semana e associei que era devido eu não acessar no fim de semana.
Mas agora notei isso de um dia para o outro durante a semana.

Qual critério o SO utiliza para isso?

Comment: Você recebeu negativos: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/35571/leandro-paix%c3%a3o?tab=reputation

Comment: Pois é Maniero, também pensei nisso, mas pelo menos para mim não aparece voto negativo desde o dia  02/03. Enfim, é só uma dúvida mesmo.

Comment: O fato de acessar ou não em determinado dia não altera em nada sua pontuação. Os únicos eventos que a alteram estão descritos na [Central de Ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) - ah, tem também os  casos em que um post é apagado, aí vc também ganha ou perde os pontos correspondentes, como se o post não tivesse existido (por exemplo, se tiver uma edição aprovada, ganha 2 pontos, mas se o post que vc editou for apagado, perde esses pontos - se receber voto negativo em uma pergunta/resposta sua, perde 2 pontos, mas se apagar, recupera esses pontos, etc).

Comment: @hkotsubo faz sentido isso mesmo, pois acompanhei alguns posts que realmente foram apagados. Show, valeu!